# Vue component, observed data is not work as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

https://jsfiddle.net/misaka1008/z24c0suf/1/
I have sample as above, when i click into "Male" radio in first row, i need click twice for "Male" is selected.

```
selectChanging: function(val){
    this.checked = val;
}
```

if i comment **this.checked = val**, it will work correct. if not comment, on first click, after execute **this.checked = val**, it is auto select back to "Female".
Why does it work like that? How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `:checked="value == keyValue"` then it will work

```
Vue.component("radio-button", {
    props: ["keyValue", "name", "value"],
  template: `<label class="nts-radiobox">
              <input ref="radio" type="radio" :name="name" v-bind:value="keyValue" :checked="value == keyValue" @change="changed(keyValue)"/>
              <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
              <slot></slot>
                    </label>`,
    methods: {
            changed: function(value){
                    this.$emit('change', value);
            }
    }
});
```

Demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/1vge7c4y/2/)